# How to load several movies' thumb image with one UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, avfoundation

I am build a media edit project that allow user do edit with several media.To meet this need,I push a `UICollectionView` in a `UICollectionViewCell`.

The inner `UICollectionView` load a movie's thumb images.

sample code:

```
- (void)setupUI
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
//    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 200);
    UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    self.collectionView = collectionView;
    collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:collectionView];
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    collectionView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    collectionView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
//    [collectionView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
//        make.edges.equalTo(self);
//    }];

    collectionView.delegate = self;
    collectionView.dataSource = self;
    [collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];


}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    PLog(@"count - %ld",self.videoItem.thumbnails.count);
    return self.thumbImages.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PLog(@"kkkkkkkkkkk,cell item %ld,cell address %@",indexPath.item,cell);
    UIImage *image = self.thumbImages[indexPath.item];
    if ([image isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        image = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [cell addSubview:imageView];
//    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [imageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(cell);
    }];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(_videoItem.thumbWidth, CollectionHeight);
}
```

The outer UICollectionView data source from several different movie, custom `UICollectionViewLayout`

sample code:

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = nil;
    PDVideoItemCollectionViewCell *videoCell = [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuse" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                    PLog(@"indexrow - %ld",indexPath.item);
                    if (videoCell.collectionView == nil) {
                        [videoCell setupUI];
                    }

                    videoCell.videoItem = [self.timelineItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
                    videoCell.videoItem.videoCell = videoCell;
                    [videoCell reloadCollectionData];

                    PLog(@"cellll - %@",videoCell);
                    cell = videoCell;
    cell.backgroundColor = MainBackgroundColor;
        return cell;
    }
```

Debug console log:

```
[PDVideoItem.m:172] image - <UIImage: 0x1268a3780>, {280, 158}--46
[PDVideoItem.m:172] image - <UIImage: 0x12689b800>, {280, 158}--47
[PDVideoItem.m:172] image - <UIImage: 0x12690a000>, {280, 158}--48
[PDVideoItem.m:172] image - <UIImage: 0x126821b60>, {280, 158}--49
[PDVideoItem.m:172] image - <UIImage: 0x1268a43d0>, {280, 158}--50
[PDVideoItem.m:184] done
[PDVideoItemCollectionViewCell.m:144]   count - 51
[PDVideoItemCollectionViewCell.m:151]   kkkkkkkkkkk,cell item 0,cell address <UICollectionViewCell: 0x12692de30; frame = (0 0; 112.5 63.2812); layer = <CALayer: 0x12691ff80>>
[PDVideoItemCollectionViewCell.m:151]   kkkkkkkkkkk,cell item 1,cell address <UICollectionViewCell: 0x126930930; frame = (112.5 0; 112.5 63.2812); layer = <CALayer: 0x12692f310>>
[PDVideoItemCollectionViewCell.m:151]   kkkkkkkkkkk,cell item 2,cell address <UICollectionViewCell: 0x1263aab60; frame = (225 0; 112.5 63.2812); layer = <CALayer: 0x12688f230>>
[PDVideoItemCollectionViewCell.m:151]   kkkkkkkkkkk,cell
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKaz1.png)

Situation description:2 movie = 2 outer UIcollectionViewCell = 2 inner UIcollectionView,total 82 thumbs = 82 inner UIcollectionViewCell
kkkkkkkkkkk log in `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method,count 25

Now get the problem that the inner UIcollectionViewCell seems do not ReUse,the memory will keep increase and UI load will be slow when I use `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to do timeline scale.And the inner UICollectionView's delegate method `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:` never invoke when I do scroll action

Uh,Actually I think the main problem is I have generated all movies thumbs at first time,but because of inner collectionViewCell do not reuse,I couldn't generate thumb according to Item Indexpath.

This project refer to Apple's application `iMovie` a lot,maybe the applicate situation I describe is not clear,just download  `iMovie`

Hope your good idea.

Comment: use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage to lazy load images in collection view

Comment: No,all these movie file is local file,generate images from movie need amount of time,SDWebImage  do cache also need spent disk memory...

Answer (score 0):

First you have a memory issue for the inner `UICollectionView` which that you add the `UIImageView` subview even if it's already added to the view's hierarchy here:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; 
[cell addSubview:imageView];
```

So you have to replace it with the following:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        PLog(@"kkkkkkkkkkk,cell item %ld,cell address %@",indexPath.item,cell);
        UIImage *image = self.thumbImages[indexPath.item];
        if ([image isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            image = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        }
        UIImageView *imageView;
        if ([cell viewWithTag: ImageView_TAG]) {
               imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
               imageView.tag = ImageView_TAG
               [cell addSubview:imageView];
        } else {
               imageView = [cell viewWithTag: ImageView_TAG]
               imageView.image = image
        }

    //    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [imageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.edges.equalTo(cell);
        }];
        return cell;
    }
```

Then for outer `UICollectionView`, you have to assign the collection view to the videoCell in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` like:

```
videoCell.collectioView = collectioView
```

This will save your memory and avoid the increasing of the memory by effective usage of reusing cells

Good Luck :)

Comment: All you say is base on the inner collectionViewCell is reusable,but actuality is I log all inner cell address is different

Comment: Sure, it's based on the number of visible cells you display. the reusability starts once you begin to scroll down.

Comment: The problem I meet is the inner collectionViewCell couldn't reuse,hope for your solution.Or you could download app iMovie,post your idea about UI and It is best to take the strategy of generate thumb from video  into consideration